# Cannot select specific column in SqlQuery - Entity Framework code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, rawsql

I have a problem when I am using `SqlQuery` method to try to get some data from database, everything is perfect if I get to all column like this:

```
data.Items.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Items WHERE iID = '1' ORDER BY iTitle")
```

But I just want to get maybe one or two columns, but that does not work and I get an error:

```
data.Items.SqlQuery("SELECT iTitle FROM dbo.Items WHERE iID = '1' ORDER BY iTitle")
```

Error:

> Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the specified '....Models.Item'. A member of the type, 'iID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Below is some code of model and dbcontext

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [Column("iID")]
    public int iID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public int iTitle { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ItemDBContext() : base("name=connectionstring") { }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I hope someone can tell me what I can do to fix this problem? I'd be extremely grateful for that <3

Comment: `var items = data.Items.Where(item => item.iID == 1).Select(item => item.iTitle);`

Comment: You're using **Entity Framework** - use its querying capabilities and stop using raw SQL :....

Answer (score 0):

if your are using entity framework with code first approach you can use below code implementation to get data

```
var itemdata = data.Items.Where(x=> x.iID.Equals(1)).OrderBy(x=> x.iTitle).toList();
```

then you can use

> itemdata

list for whatever you want. hope this will help you!